# How to rename large amounts of spatial data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have approximately 1500 raster files following this format:

```
m_3609922_nw_14_1_20100425
```

I need these subsetted to, for example: `3609922nw`.  What are appropriate methods to rename large numbers of spatial data, that may or may not contain ancillary files (e.g. .xml, .ovr)?

Comment: Does it have to be ArcPy? If the filenames are that uniform, it is easy to create a batch file that does what you want using a combination of Excel and a text editor. Otherwise, with moderate difficulty (no more that ArcPy) you could write a batch file that uses regex to rename the files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this ought to get you going...

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# directory containing rasters to be renamed
RASTER_DIR = 'C:/MyRasters/'

env.workspace = RASTER_DIR
for raster in arcpy.ListRasters():

    # get the raster name and file extension
    fileName,fileExtension = os.path.splitext(raster)

    # do some shenanigans to rename the file
    # based on your sample raster name, fileNameParts would look like
    # fileNameParts[0] = m
    # fileNameParts[1] = 3609922
    # fileNameParts[2] = nw
    # fileNameParts[3] = 14
    # fileNameParts[4] = 1
    # fileNameParts[5] = 20100425

    fileNameParts = fileName.split('_')
    compactFileName = fileNameParts[1] + fileNameParts[2] + fileExtension

    arcpy.Rename_management(raster,compactFileName)
```

Comment: How can I shorten the filename, but keep the underscores? e.g. instead of m_3609922_nw_14_1_20100425 , I would like to remove the "m_" to return 3609922_nw_14_1_20100425. Basically, I would like to remove the first 'x' number of characters from a filename.

Comment: hmm I added + "_" +  between each file part, there must be a more efficient method..